# Iterative JSON data and accessing the data with JQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I have the following JSON data being returned by a webservice:

```
    {"d":[
{"RelationshipManager":{},"AdvisoryId":13,"ClientId":22,"UserId":13,"AdvisoryMessage":"Welcome!","Seen":false,"Issued":"\/Date(1312123970110)\/","Delivered":null,"Importance":3},
{"RelationshipManager":{},"AdvisoryId":14,"ClientId":22,"UserId":13,"AdvisoryMessage":"A really long boring message.","Seen":false,"Issued":"\/Date(1312123970113)\/","Delivered":null,"Importance":1},
{"RelationshipManager":{},"AdvisoryId":15,"ClientId":22,"UserId":13,"AdvisoryMessage":"Another really long boring message.","Seen":false,"Issued":"\/Date(1312123970113)\/","Delivered":null,"Importance":1},
]}
```

What I'm trying to do is access each item using Jquery and push this into a jGrowl notification. I can't seem to get passed the initial phase of `alert`ing the data out:

```
$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "http://xxx/Service/Assets.asmx/GetUnreadAdvisories",
                data: "{'sessionHash':'<%=Session["SessionHash"].ToString()%>'}",
                contentType: "application/json",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (msg) {
                    if (msg["d"].length > 0) {
                        var data = $.parseJSON(msg.d);

                        $.each(msg, function() {
                            alert(msg.AdvisoryMessage);                                
                            $.jGrowl(msg.AdvisoryMessage, { sticky: true, theme: 'info' });

                        })

                    } else {
                        alert('no fish');
                        return false;
                    }
                },
                error: function (msg) {
                    alert(msg);
                }
            });
```

I know this question is pretty noob, but late night help is appreciated :)

Comment: This might just be a syntax error, try adding a semicolon at the end of the $.each() statement.

Comment: If you're not seeing any error, then perhaps everything *is* working but your jgrowl messages are hidden/unstyled somewhere. Have you tried just calling `$.jGrowl('hello')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is a little confused.
1) you don't need to use parseJSON - jquery is giving you an object (msg), not the json string
2) you check the array length of msg['d'] but then try and iterate through msg, which is an object with a single property (d)

Also, you don't need the (admittedly small) jquery overhead for your loop

```
var i = 0, size = msg['d'].length;
while (i < size) {
  alert(msg['d'][i]['AdvisoryMessage']);
  i++;
}
```

Comment: Perfect! This was exactly what I needed.  I was writing the original code at 3am and looking back - may need to have gone to bed! +1

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to iterate through data since you are parsing msg.d and assigning it to data variable. Try this

```
var data = $.parseJSON(msg.d);

                        $.each(data, function() {
                            alert(msg.AdvisoryMessage);                                
                            $.jGrowl(msg.AdvisoryMessage, { sticky: true, theme: 'info' });

                        });
```

Answer (score -1):

```
contentType: "application/json",
```

This is wrong. This is the content type of when you are *sending* not what you are getting. And I highly doubt you are sending json.

And as someone else mentioned, you don't need to `$.parseJSON(msg.d)` - doing `dataType: 'json'` already causes it to be parsed.